# Setting GNU readline prompt to NULL causes custom prompt to be overwritten

Tags: c, readline

I am writing a custom shell in c, and have encountered a strange little bug, which can be seen in the following testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
  while(true) {
    fprintf(stdout, "input: ");
    char *line = readline(NULL);

    if(line) {
      add_history(line);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The program spits out the prompt, and if I type something like this:

```
input: foo bar baz
```

And then go to erase the line, input: gets erased as well (once I hit the first character I inputted). Is there anyway to fix this? The only thing I could think to do was `fflush(stdout)` but that didn't work.

Comment: You are aware return 0; is implied at the end of a program, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no rule saying I need to add return 0; to the end of my file. Considering that without it still valid and correct C, and you don't know that the program did in fact exit successfully.

Comment: Right. And as I said: return 0; at the end of a program is implied, if not already present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78584/discussion-between-subinoy-and-dtscode).

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't do `readline("input: ")`?

Comment: @ace: That's certainly the solution I'd use.  I was just finishing up the testing for my answer (having written it) when I saw a comment had arrived; I hit submit, and lo, there was your question — posted within about a minute of my answer, even though the question had been inactive for 9 hours or so.  Weird the way the timing works.

Comment: Nice job on creating an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) from the start.  Thanks!

Comment: @ace: I figured this might come up. The short answer is this: https://github.com/DTSCode/dtshell/blob/master/shell_getline.c And according to #gnu readline() has no printf-like version, so I decided to create my own

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks! Asking a lot of questions on IRC certainly helped!

Comment: You can use `sprintf()` and friends to build the string then pass it to `readline()`.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking of doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell `readline()` about the prompt:

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *line;
    while ((line = readline("input: ")) != 0)
        add_history(line);
    return 0;
}
```

When you do the prompting yourself, `readline()` doesn't know about the presence of the prompt, and therefore mishandles redrawing the line when you erase the last character you entered (moving the cursor back to the beginning of the line).  When it knows about the prompt, it doesn't erase it.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So in the case of the actual file causing the issue ( https://github.com/DTSCode/dtshell/blob/master/shell_getline.c ) I would need to build the string instead of printing it, and then just have readline print the string?

Comment: Yes. That's what I do in the code I went to check before responding